# Sublime Text Editor 3 - subl doesn't open file in Windows 10 bash

Tags: sublime-text, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using bash from Windows 10 and installed Sublime Text Editor 3. However, when I tried to open a file using subl command, it's giving me the following error:

```
Unable to load libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_cairo_create from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_cursor_new_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_cursor_unref from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_display_get_default from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_display_get_pointer from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_pop from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_error_trap_push from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_input_add from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_input_remove from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_keyval_to_unicode from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_region_get_rectangles from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_default from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_height from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgb_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_rgba_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_root_window from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_width from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_n_monitors from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_point from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_screen_get_resolution from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_unicode_to_keyval from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_window_get_frame_extents from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_window_get_origin from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_window_get_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_window_invalidate_rect from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_window_set_cursor from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_window_move_resize from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_server_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_x11_get_xatom_by_name_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gdk_x11_window_set_user_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_accel_group_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_box_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_box_pack_start from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_label from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_set_active from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_clear from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_get from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_with_data from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_store from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_clipboard_wait_for_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_container_add from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_container_get_children from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_container_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_container_remove from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_dialog_add_button from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_dialog_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_dialog_run from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_dialog_set_default_response from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_drag_dest_set from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_drag_finish from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_add_filter from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_filename from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_files from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation from libgtk-
x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_select_multiple from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_add_pattern from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_file_filter_set_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_get_current_event_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_im_context_filter_keypress from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_im_context_set_client_window from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_im_multicontext_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_init from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_init_check from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_main from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_main_quit from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
Unable to load gtk_menu_attach_to_widget from libgtk-x11-2.0.so    
Unable to load gtk_menu_bar_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note to close voter: WSL questions [are on-topic for the site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-the-same-as-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do/15230#15230).

Comment: Why are you trying to run sublime in a bash shell, and not just on Windows?

Comment: You can't install arbitrary Debian packages on WSL and expect them to work. The software needs to be compatible with the WSL run time environment and Sublime Text likely isn't because it has a native build for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around this issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/